# Python mysql show content from unknown number of columns with loop

Tags: python, mysql, loops

I have a MySQL table with a number of row That I do not know. 
I managed to show the content of the first 3 rows using this function :

```
def read_some_data():
   read_query_bis = """SELECT * FROM """ + table_name + " ;"
   cursor.execute(read_query_bis)
   rows = cursor.fetchall()
   print("*** DEBUG FUNCTION Read",cursor.rowcount,"row(s) of data.")
   # Print first 3 columns of all rows
   for row in rows:
       print("*** DEBUG FUNCTION Data row = (%s, %s, %s)" %(str(row[0]), str(row[1]), str(row[2])))
```

The number of columns is unkown, Is there a way using fetchall and a loop to get all rows and all columns instead of a given number ( 3 for all row in my example )  ?

EDIT : As for the Remarque below, I could add something like :

```
Rows_var_placeholders = ", ".join(["%s"] * Rows_Lengh)
```

which cloud give me :

```
%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s
```

That I could use, but my question is more for the "str(row[0]"

Comment: try `len(row)`?

Comment: Yes, i though about that, but I do dot want to do loop like : "for i in len(row) print" because, it would show in a sequential way, which i do not want.

Comment: I could do something "Rows_var_placeholders = ", ".join(["%s"] * Rows_Lengh)" to get (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) but how should I proceed for the "str(row[i])" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [cursor.description](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-description.html) to access the returned columns.

In my example below I have built the debug string with a placeholder for each column, and used the newer [.format()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method as it allows tuple expansion.

```
def read_some_data():
    read_query_bis = """SELECT * FROM """ + table_name + " ;"
    cursor.execute(read_query_bis)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    print("*** DEBUG FUNCTION Read",cursor.rowcount,"row(s) of data.")
    for row in rows:
        # Create a placeholder for each column
        placeholder = ','.join(['{:s}']*len(cursor.description))
        # Map each col tuple to a str
        items = [str(v) for v in cursor.description]
        # Add the placeholder to the debug string
        debug_str = "*** DEBUG FUNCTION Data row = ({:s})".format(placeholder)
        # Print the debug string with the expanded list of column tuples
        print(debug_str.format(*items))
```

Here is an example that I tested with:

```
desc = [('col1', 'a'), ('col2', 'b'), ('col3', 'c'), ('col4', 'd')]
placeholder = ','.join(['{:s}']*len(desc))
items = [str(v) for v in desc]
debug_str = "*** DEBUG FUNCTION Data row = ({:s})".format(placeholder)
print(debug_str.format(*items))
```

Output:

```
*** DEBUG FUNCTION Data row = (('col1', 'a'),('col2', 'b'),('col3', 'c'),('col4', 'd'))
```

Comment: Thanks ! I take it ! Marked as answered and upvoted your answer !